# I want to return to a previous month from a particular month (which are given in combo box) not from a date

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make payroll every month for the previous month. Till now I am doing it manually on excel. Now I want to create this every month through VBA. So I have created a userform where in there are three comboboxes. In 1st, I select Company name that I want to make payroll for, in 2nd combobox, months from January to December are given and in 2nd years are given.

The value in **1st combo box** is a list given in thisworkbook itself. The value in 2nd and 3rd comboboxes (month and year Comboboxes) is from below mentioned code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim i As Integer
With Me.cmbmonth1
    For i = 1 To 12
        .AddItem VBA.Format(VBA.DateSerial(2021, i, 1), "mmmm")
    Next i
    
        .Value = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm")

End With

For i = VBA.Year(Date) - 1 To VBA.Year(Date) + 20
    Me.cmbyear.AddItem i
Next i
    .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "yyyy")
    If Me.cmbmonth1.Value = "December" Then
    Me.cmbyear.Value = Format(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date), ("yyyy"))
    Else
    Me.cmbyear.Value = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    End If
    
End Sub
```

1st of all I want to create a folder for the month for which I want to make payroll. For that I have created code and month folder is being easily created.

**Now come to the question.**
I want to copy the previous month payroll sheet which was created in the previous month. For example, this month I have to create payroll for June 2021. For creating this I have to copy payroll sheet from the folder of month May 2021 (I call this previous month) and paste it in June 2021 folder. After that I will make the required change like addition or deletion of employees and marking their attendance.

I am looking for a code that can copy payrollsheet from the month folder that is  previous month from the month that I select in 2nd combo box. For Example If I select June 2021 in comboboxes that payroll sheet should be copied from May 2021 (which is already there) and be pasted in June 2021 folder. If I select May 2021 in comboboxes then payroll sheet should be copied from April 2021 and so on...

I have tried codes like below and have commented many when these were not able to perform the desired task.

```
Private Sub CmdSubmit_Click()

Dim startPath As String
Dim myName As String
Dim myName1 As String
Dim previousmonthpayroll As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim mm As Date
Dim previousMonth
'Dim exampledate As Date



On Error Resume Next
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(#12:00:03 AM#))
startPath = "C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\ESI PF"
mm = 22 - Me.cmbmonth1.Value - 2021
previousMonth = VBA.Format(VBA.DateSerial(Year(mm), Month(mm) - 1, Day(mm)), "mmmm")
'exampledate = DateValue("me.cmbmonth1.value 1,2020")



myName = Me.cmbCompanyName.Text & Application.PathSeparator & Me.cmbmonth1.Value & " " & Me.cmbyear.Text
myName1 = Me.cmbCompanyName.Text & Application.PathSeparator & previousMonth & " " & Me.cmbyear.Value ' for previous month

Dim folderpathwithname As String
Dim folderpathwithname1 As String   ' for previous month

folderpathwithname = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName
folderpathwithname1 = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1   ' for previous month

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If Dir(folderpathwithname, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        fso.Createfolder folderpathwithname
    
      '  End If
      Else
'Dim PayrollName As String
'Dim PreviousMonthfolder As Folder

Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & """", vbNormalFocus
'Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & folderpathwithname1 & """", vbNormalFocus


'PayrollName = "Master Payroll" & "_" & Me.cmbmonth1.Value & " " & Me.cmbyear.Value & "_" & Me.cmbCompanyName.Value
'PreviousMonthfolder = startPath & "\" & Me.cmbCompanyName.Value
'previousmonthpayroll = ("startPath & " \ " & Me.cmbCompanyName.Value & " \ " Me.cmbmonth1.Value-1 & " " & Me.cmbyear.Value & " \ " Master Payroll*.xl??")

 

End If
'If PayrollName = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
 '   previousmonthpayroll.Select
  '  Selection.Copy
   ' VBA.FileSystem.Dir(folderpathwithname, vbDirectory).pastspecial
    
'Else
'Exit Sub
'End If


'Dim filename As String
'filename = VBA.FileSystem.Dir("C:\Users\dell\Google Drive\Goods and Service Tax-GST\Arun Kumar\Testing*.xl??")
'If filename = VBA.Constants.vbNullString Then
'MsgBox "File doesn't Exist"
'Else
'Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\dell\Google Drive\Goods and Service Tax-GST\Arun Kumar\Testing Master Payroll.xlsx"
'End If

        
        
        
        
'ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=folderpathwithname
'Dim PayrollName As String
'Dim PreviousMonthPayroll As String
'PayrollName = "Master Payroll" & "_" & Me.cmbmonth1.Value & " " & Me.cmbyear.Value & "_" & Me.cmbCompanyName.Value
'PreviousMonthPayroll = "Master Payroll" & "_" & Me.cmbmonth1.Value - 1 & " " & Me.cmbyear.Value & "_" & Me.cmbCompanyName.Value

'If Dir(folderpathwithname & "\" & PayrollName & ".xlsx") = "" Then
'GoTo folderpathwithname1


'Dir(folderpathwithname1 & "\" & PreviousMonthPayroll & ".xlsx").Copy

'Dir(folderpathwithname).PasteSpecial


'Workbooks.Add
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs folderpathwithname & "\" & PayrollName & ".xlsx"
'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Payroll Sheet"
'ActiveWorkbook.Save
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
'Dir(folderpathwithname, vbDirectory) = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Request all to help

Thanks
Preet

Comment: What did you try by your own? How did you load the combo? Using an array or month by month?

Comment: What does "**return** to previous month" mean? What exactly are the values in the combobox (text like "January" or "Jan" or "1")? What should happen if the current month is January? • Please [edit] your question give some input/output example data and show what you have tried to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your combo box is cboMonth.  It stores the following array:

```
1   Jan
2   Fem
3   Mar
4   Apr
```

etc...

The first column is hidden, the second column is what displays.  So, from anywhere else on the form, you can say (this is "air code", my VBA skills are a bit rusty)

```
Set A = 0
' If the month is January, you need to go back to December
If me.cboMonth.Value = 1 then
  A = 12
'Otherwise, just subtract 1 from the month number
else
  A = me.cboMonth.Value - 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for trying for helping me Johnny but this is not what I was looking for. Please read question now, I have elaborated question and now it should be more clear to understand the problem

Comment: @DrishtiConsultancy - You need to use the FileCopy command to do this.  Structured like: FileCopy "C:\Users\marks\Documents\Folder\Original File.xlsx", 
    "C:\Users\marks\Documents\New Folder\Copied File.xlsx"